# Can compacting arrays be more selective in JSON-LD framing?

Tags: json-ld, rdflib

In the question [JSON-LD framing single object arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849997/json-ld-framing-single-object-arrays) was asked on how to make arrays from single objects while framing JSON-LD for all arrays (by adding an compactArrays option).

Is there any way to do it selectively? Starting from always having "@graph", and after that for some "major" nodes. Maybe some parameter can be given in the frame to indicate exception of the general option?

In my case arrays are actually sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you can do it per-property by setting the `@collection` attribute of the property to `@set`:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "arrayProperty": {
      "@id": "http://example.com/something",
      "@container": "@set"
    }
  },
  ...
  "arrayProperty": []
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! The only change I needed  "myProperty": {} (because of getting empty array). What is the difference between {} and [] in this case?

Comment: Works also in another case, like: "myProp": [{"@type": "SomeType", "@embed": True }], so I guess the question is fully answered.